limit of a function of two variables defined in two regions + a curve
Let $f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}f_1(x,y)& if & x\in A \\ f_2(x,y)& if & x\in C\\f_3(x,y) & if & x\in B \end{array} \right.$,
where $A=\{(x,y):x<0\}, C=\{(x,y):x=0\}, B=\{(x,y):x>0\}$.
Suppose

$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\ x\in A}} f_1(x,y)=L$,
$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\ x\in C}} f_2(x,y)=L$,
$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\ x\in B}} f_3(x,y)=L$.

Question 1: Can I conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=L$?
In the general case: Suppose $f(x,y)$ is defined as above under the same assumptions 1, 2, and 3, but where $C$ is a curve that separates the plane into two regions, say $A$ and $B$.
Question 2: Must $C$ satisfy any conditions in order to conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} f(x,y)=L$, where $(a,b)$ is an accumulation point of $A, C$ and $B$?
Thanks in advance!

Even more generally, let $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ be any finite collection of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ whose union contains a neighbourhood of $p \in \mathbb R^n$.  If $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \to p\\ x\in A_i}} f(x)=L$ for each $i$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to p} f(x) = L$. It's an easy $\epsilon-\delta$ proof: given $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta_i$ that works for each $i$, and $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \ldots, \delta_m)$.
This would also work in any metric space instead of $\mathbb R^n$.
